# Find all the matches in file with findall() and print the whole line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to achieve this task. But, facing road blocks.
Task is,

1. READ THE FILE
2. SEARCH FOR A WORD, find all occurrences
3. PRINT THE LINE OF THE MATCHED PATTERN

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a basic way to achieve this**

**Define the finder**

```
def parse_file(file_path: str, word_to_find: str):
    if not isinstance(file_path, str):
        raise Exception("'file_path' should be string.")

    if not isinstance(word_to_find, str):
        raise Exception("'word_to_find' should be string.")

    with open(file_path, 'r') as file1:
        lines = file1.readlines()

    matched_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        if line.find(word_to_find) != -1:
            matched_lines.append(line)

    return matched_lines
```

**Calling the function**

```
matches = parse_file('data_file.txt', 'find_this_word')


for item in matches:
    print(item)
```